# Toolbar Back Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-toolbar

I made a transition animation from one activity to another via clickListener. Now I want to add it on the back button of the Toolbar to go back. I already set the parent activities, but I have no idea how to implement animation on the back button.

[image]

Comment: override onBackPress and add transition and then call finish.

Comment: that works only if I go back with a back button and not with a toolbar arrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the onBackPressed() method and apply your transition and call finish. To handle toolbar back click event override following method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```